# Linux kernel function takes unused void pointer argument

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Why does [this function](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/oom_kill.c?h=v5.10-rc7#n640) in the Linux kernel take a `void *unused` parameter that serves no purpose in the body of the function?

Comment: Hint: the function is started via `kthread_run()`.

Comment: TL/DR Wall of code.  I can guess, however, that the pointer is to allow user-defined context to be  supplied in the call and, later, be retrieved in a callback.

Comment: Information necessary to answer a question should be in the question itself. External pages change and vanish, and Stack Overflow is intended to be a durable repository of questions and answers. If a question can be understood only by visiting an external link, it is not suitably presented for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is a callback.
The prototype of all callbacks used in this context must be equal, sometimes may have an unused parameter.

`kthread_run` resquires a function like this in the first parameter:

```
int cb(void *param);
```